# How can I write conditional interceptor in Axios

Tags: axios

I am able to add an interceptor for the Axios pipeline. Also, I need the loader to be conditional based. The situation is some requests can run in the background and don't need a loader to be blocking the UI. In such cases, I will be able to let the Axios know by sending an extra parameter saying isBackground call. How can I achieve this?

```
      axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
            this.isLoading = true; // Or trigger start loader
            return config
        }, (error) => {
            this.isLoading = false  // Or trigger stoploader
            return Promise.reject(error)
        })

        axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
            this.isLoading = false    // Or trigger stoploader
            return response
        }, function(error) {
            this.isLoading = false   // Or trigger stoploader
            return Promise.reject(error)
        })
```

Comment: You can create a function that gets called with all the axios calls. Inside you have a if-block that checks a paramter you provide if the axios logic should be in background or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use your own custom property `isBackground` on the config like this:

```js
  axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    console.log(config.isBackground)
    return config
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error.config.isBackground)
    return Promise.reject(error)
  })

  axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    console.log(response.config.isBackground)
    return response
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error.config.isBackground)
    return Promise.reject(error)
  })

  const config = {
    isBackground: true
  }

    axios.get('https://httpbin.org/get', config)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Note that there is a [bug](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2295) in current release 0.19.0 waiting to be fixed, which breaks this functionality. Works ok in version 0.18...

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0strbwm8/2/)

Comment: That's ugly, but since Axios doesn't seem to support multiple instances, so there's no other way. When I said ugly, I mean why should we let interceptors know when they should be applied.

Comment: Oh no, I just read Axios docs. It says it supports adding interceptors to a custom instance of axios.